# Cross-browser BSD-style sockets or Node.js streams

Tags: node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io

I'm in the process of implementing a streaming protocol in JavaScript. The protocol is defined in terms of byte streams, not messages. I'd like to be able to talk to browsers using this protocol.

I've used Socket.io in the past for easy cross-browser full-duplex networking. However, in this case, I need BSD-style sockets. Ideally, I could code to the Node.js streams API and have the same (or very similar) code work in the browser.

Is there something like Socket.io for byte streams? ie Well tested, cross-browser, multi-transport, heart beating, etc.

Answer (score 0):

So far, http://binaryjs.com/ is the closest to what I need. Unfortunately, the documentation suggests it is somewhat immature. I'd be very happy to find a more stable library with wider browser support.

Answer (score 0):

Socket.IO uses lots of tech behind the scenes in order to make it very accessible and reliable. Lots of users will have Long Polling fallback, which is just pure HTTP protocol.
While WebSockets do support binary type of messages, it will be not the same as Long Polling or any other fallback tech, so Socket.IO will not support it as far as it is not something on all transports.

As well WebSockets and Socket.IO is purely Message Based communication protocol. In case with WebSockets it has framing around each message which will drive overhead for streaming.
What you need is Stream based communication, but not Message based. As I am aware this is long topic, and still not clear in web world.

Although you could look into WebRTC as future possibility for streaming data and it might meet your needs.
Some other options is to use plugins or extensions for browsers, like flash, unity, bespoke stuff and so on, in order to enable real streaming features.